# Gmap.net with sqlite db

Tags: c#, sqlite, gmap.net

I am planning to design a Windows form application using `GMap.Net` for viewing offline map for personal use. I already have some `mapdata` which I downloaded by use of universal map `downloader` which can be converted to `sqlite` db format. But `Gmap.net` uses cache in `gmdb` format. Can I convert the `sqlite` db to `gmdb` format? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLlite to access the gmdb file, it's the same format.

just use

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GMap.NET\TileDBv5\en\Data.gmdb;Version=3;");
```

see http://mobac.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=278 for tables